# Balancing oriented graph

Tags: c#, linq

I have a set of edges looking like this:

```
public class Edge<T>
{
    public T From { get; set; }
    public T To { get; set; }
}
```

Now I would like to check if my graph is balanced. Under "balanced" I mean that any vertex have equal count of incoming and outgoing edges. My current code is:

```
public static bool IsGraphBalanced<T>(List<Edge<T>> edges)
{
    var from = new Dictionary<T, int>);
    var to = new Dictionary<T, int>);

    foreach (var edge in edges)
    {
        if (!from.ContainsKey(edge.From))
            from.Add(edge.From, 0);

        if (!to.ContainsKey(edge.To))
            to.Add(edge.To, 0);

        from[edge.From] += 1;
        to[edge.To] += 1;
    }

    foreach (var kv in from)
    {
        if (!to.ContainsKey(kv.Key))
            return false;
        if (to[kv.Key] != kv.Value)
            return false;
    }
    // mirrored check with foreach on "to" dictionary

    return true;
}
```

Can I replace it with Linq?

P.S. Size of `edges` is under 100-150 items, so I care about a readability rather than performance

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to query your vertexes in this case? Assuming you have a vertex object, you could make a method that returns edgesFromCount/edgesToCount

Comment: @hellyale my verticies is a list of `T`. How can I get `edgesFromCount` from this list?

Comment: Are you sure the check `if (to.ContainsKey(kv.Key))` is correct? Looks like it should be `if (!...)`

Comment: @IvanStoev you are right, it's a typo. Should I update a question? If I do so your comment will not be meaningful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a more concise implementation utilizing `Enumerable` class [`ToLookup`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup(v=vs.110).aspx), [`All`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541(v=vs.110).aspx), [`Count`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx) extension methods (I'll let you decide whether it's more readable or not):

```
public static bool IsGraphBalanced<T>(List<Edge<T>> edges)
{
    var from = edges.ToLookup(e => e.From);
    var to = edges.ToLookup(e => e.To);
    return from.All(g => g.Count() == to[g.Key].Count())
        && to.All(g => from[g.Key].Any());
}
```

The `ToLookup` method is similar to `GroupBy`, but creates a reusable data structure (because we'll need 2 passes).

Then `from.All(g => g.Count() == to[g.Key].Count())` checks if every `From` has corresponding `To` and their counts match. Note that in case the key doesn't exist, the `ILookup<TKey, TElement>` indexer does not throw exception or return `null`, but returns an empty `IEnumerable<TElement>`, which allows us to combine the checks.

Finally the `to.All(g => from[g.Key].Any())` checks if every `To` has corresponding `From`. There is no need to check the counts here because they have been checked in the previous step.